# Enable Remote API on Docker hosts in Ubuntu 14

Tags: docker

I am running 'Docker version 1.10.3, build 20f81dd' on Ubuntu 14.04. Now my requirement is to create/delete/manage new container from the REST API (HTTP) from outside world. So, for this how could I enable Docker to run on a port.

It will be helpful if I get details step as in net I tried few but didn't work.

Comment: Have you looked at docker machine? It will automatically install and configure docker with a secure remote API capability. See: https://docs.docker.com/machine/. There is a generic driver for existing servers: https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/generic/

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution and it's very easy at all. Here is the configuration.

Got To:

```
vi /etc/default/docker
```

Add `DOCKER_OPTS="-H tcp://127.0.0.1:2375"`

restart docker service.

Run `netstat -lnp` and see docker is running on port 2375

Comment: Your should consider protecting the port. https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/